# How to click on visible text under a class?

Tags: autoit

I created an AutoIt script for a program that has a navigator bar
like this :

[image]

Using Au3Info.exe I'm getting following info:

[image][image]

So the problem is **Encode** tab is active and I want the script to click on the **Decode** tab, but Au3Info.exe is only identifying the navigator bar :

[image]

I'm only getting mouse coordinates or Visible Text for both tabs. I tried :

```
Run("C:\Users\Dumpty\Desktop\Selenium\WebPconvPortable\WebPconv.exe")
WinWaitActive("Romeolight WebPconv")
Sleep(3000)
ControlFocus("Romeolight WebPconv", "", "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.378734a62")
ControlClick("Romeolight WebPconv", "", "[CLASS:WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.378734a62;CONTROLCLICK COORDS:165, 9]")
```

I tried to click using mouse coordinates too but that's not working either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `MouseClick` as you have object position available.
Go to `AutoIt v3 Window info` and select the Mouse tab.
get the position mentioned over of object. and use in below code.

[image]

Below is code you can try:

```
Run("C:\Users\Dumpty\Desktop\Selenium\WebPconvPortable\WebPconv.exe")
WinWaitActive("Romeolight WebPconv")
Sleep(3000)
MouseClick("left",0,51)==> use actual value
```

Please let me know if this worked.

Comment: Yeah it worked but isn't there any other way than this? because if i want to run that script on other machine then it might not work coz of window position...

Comment: `Opt("MouseCoordMode", 2)` (at top of script) can change to using relative co-ordinates to the client area of the active window, instead of the screen. Use same settings in *AutoIt Info Tool* to get the new co-ordinates for `MouseClick`. This may help if the window is in a different position.